# Are there any major differences between the movie tie-in edition of Arthur Spiderwick's Field Guide and the original edition?

Tags: textual-history, holly-black

Does the movie tie-in edition of *Arthur Spiderwick's Field Guide to the Fantastic World Around You* only have a different cover (compared to the original edition), or are there also changes to the text and contents?

To clarify:

- I mean the two actual books that you can buy (see [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0689859414) and [this](http://www.simonandschuster.com/books/Arthur-Spiderwicks-Field-Guide-to-the-Fantastical-World-Around-You/Tony-DiTerlizzi/The-Spiderwick-Chronicles/9781416960959)). Thanks to Rand al' Thor for providing the links.
- And I am asking whether there are any significant differences (besides the cover) between the two editions i.e. photos in the movie edition.

*This is an example question. It is linked to a [meta question](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/are-questions-about-different-editions-of-a-book-on-topic) asking whether it is on topic.*